# C++ class friendship

Tags: c++

I am writing code to access private members of a class through another friend class. The below code works

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    private:
    int a;
    protected:
    public:

    friend class Bar;


    Foo(int x)
    {
        a = x ;
    }
};

class Bar
{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
    int b;

    Bar(Foo& f)
    {
        b = f.a;
        cout << "f.a is " << f.a << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(5);
    Bar bar(foo);

    cout << "Value of variable b is " << bar.b << endl;
}
```

Above code works fine. However, if I want to access a private variable of `Foo` through a function in friend class `Bar`, I am unable to. See code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    private:
    int a;
    protected:
    public:

    friend class Bar;


    Foo(int x)
    {
        a = x ;
    }
};

class Bar
{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
    int b;

    Bar(Foo& f)
    {
        b = f.a;
    }
    void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << f.a << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(5);
    Bar bar(foo);

    cout << "Value of variable b is " << bar.b << endl;
}
```

I totally understand why execution fails on the

```
void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << f.a << endl;
    }
```

function since f is not in scope for the function. However, since I am passing `Foo f` in the constructor for `Bar b`, I am hoping to write code that will allow me to access members in `Foo` without passing `Foo f` to the function `printvariable()` again.

What is the most efficient way to write this code?

Comment: long story short, friendship is bad. Do yourself a favor, stick to OOP Principles and SOLID principles (Encapsulation, in this case). Not every language feature must be used, i.e. goto.

Comment: Add a variable of type `Foo &` to `Bar` and the constructor assign `f` to the variable. Then use the member variable in `printvariable`.

Comment: @EyalPerry: you're wrong. learn more about it http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#friend - actually, `friend` is additional, precise, ultra-fine access modifier. It enables even more encapsulation, because it defines one specific target, not like public/protected which allow unlimited number of grantees. Encapsulation is not about making things private! It's about limiting access to those who need it and are expected to get it.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl. All I mean is that this feature "facilitates" abuse, and that you can manage without it. Therefore, one must exercise caution when applying it. TBH, I mostly develop in C#, where there's no such feature. One CAN manage without it,  and IMHO, one should NOT use it.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl. Enabling access to private members is a highway to bugs. As the "befriended" class mutates, so should it's friends. This, IMHO, is a design smell.

Comment: @EyalPerry: well, show me a case, where you changed a `public` API of a class and it haven't caused further changes*). When you use `friend` you make a layer of `private API`. It's just another option. And when API changes, things change too. You can shoot yourself in the foot with `public/protected` easier than friend, both are easily abuse-able. In terms of C#, did you know that `explicit interface implementation` produces **private** methods accessible by casting to given interface? It works in a different way than friend, but it seems public/protected/+internal was still not enough :)

Comment: *) and then compare the number of classes too-public/protected, with classes too-friendly over a couple of C++ projects.. I bet that first two are much more abused.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl. When an API changes, clients change. When a private field changes, or when a private method is removed. In a "friendless" language, clients are uneffected. impl details should not be exposed due to exactly that. If you so wish to expose certain properties and methods of a class to one client and certain aspects to another, you clearly have a design problem. Namely: your class most likely breaks the single responsibility principle. explicit interfaces do not serve the purpose you described. They merely enable polymorphism while leaving a clean, noiseless public API.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I really did not understand the shorter comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @EyalPerry You aren't making much sense. When private members change, the clients must also change because the internals of a class matter, regardless of their access level. That is the way it is in C++. Extending the interface of a class via a set of friend functions is no more dangerous and offers no less encapsulation than having public members accessing private ones.

Comment: @juanchopanza. If a change in a private member causes clients to change, That means you have not properly designed your class. This is not "me" making or not making sense. I mean this with utmost respect. A public API must "ensure" some behavior or change in state. The only reason for a client of a public API to change is if the public API changes, not if its internal private methods change.

Comment: @EyalPerry 1/2 In C++, a data member, regardless of its access, affects the size and layout of a type. A non-public member function participates in overload resolution. So whatever you do to the privates of a can affects the clients. At the very least you force all clients to re-compile. It is just a feature of the language, unfortunately. This is independent of how clean the public interface of a class may be.

Comment: @EyalPerry 2/2 One could argue that non-member friends actually help encapsulation by allowing to abstract away behaviour from the layout of a type and the overload resolution set of its members.   And the coupling of friends to the non-public members of a class is no higher than that of member functions. Friendship may have more value in languages that really hide away non-public attributes.

Comment: @juanchopanza. You C++ guys are insane (in a good way). Thank you for enriching my knowledge. At no point did I regard compilation- I only related to the architectural and interactional ramifications of API change. Which is, IMHO- what is most important in today's fast pace-evolving applications.

Comment: @EyalPerry Unfortunately to be effective still requires knowing a lot of stuff that is irrelevant in other languages. We often need to consider ABIs as well as APIs.

Comment: @juanchopanza. I will leave effectiveness to build machines and hosting hardware. That is all there is to do, in my layer.

Comment: @EyalPerry: re explicit interface impl: I did not say it worked like `friend`! I just said, that the way this **actually** works,is almost like defining another kind of semi-private access modifier. The compiler makes those methods private. You can check it via reflection. But they _are not_ private, because they are accessible by (i.e. public) interface.  re short comment: I was refferring to you saying that `friend` easily leads to abuse. I countered it with asking you to look through some C++ projects and count classes that use friend too much vs. classes that use public/protected too much.

Comment: btw, I've just read what juanchopanza wrote. He expressed the 'API change' much better than I managed to. and "lot of irrelevant stuff" - so true.. Anyways, please don't treat my previous comment as bumping up the argument - I just wanted to clarify what I wrote up above since at some point you asked what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the reference to `f`. The code should be:

```
class Bar
{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
    int b;
    Foo& f_ref;

    Bar(Foo& f)
    :f_ref(f)
    {
        b = f.a;
    }
    void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << f_ref.a << endl;
    }

};
```

[TEST!](http://ideone.com/IkkuUS)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but if I were you I'd write some getters, also – class friendship isn't really recommended.

```
class Bar {
public:
    Foo& ref;

    Bar(Foo& f)
        : ref { f }
    { }
    void printvariable() {
        cout << "f.a is " << ref.a << endl;
    }
};
```

Btw there's no reason to add `void` in brackets in C++, it lost its meaning from C and has no effect by now.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in one point. You are indeed passing a reference to `f` in the ctor, but the constructor and whole `class Bar` **does not remember** a **whole** object of `f`. In your original code, the constructor only makes the Bar object remember the `int a` part of the object, so only that little bit is later accessible:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    friend class Bar;
    ...
};

class Bar
{
    ...
    int b;

    Bar(Foo& f)
    {
        b = f.a;    // <=--- HERE
    }

    void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << b << endl;  // <-- now it refers B
    }
```

Please note how your ctor of Bar only reads `f.a` and stores it in `b`. From now on, the Bar object only remembers `b` and that's all. You can freely access the `b` in `printvariable`. However, it will not be the `a`-taken-from-`f`. It will be `b`, that was set to the same value as f.a during constructor. Since that point of time, `b` and `f.a` are totally separate. That's how value copying works.

To make Bar remember **whole** `f`, you have to, well, remember **whole** f:

```
class Bar
{
    ...
    Foo wholeThing;

    Bar(Foo& f)
    {
        wholeThing = f;    // <=--- HERE
    }

    void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << wholeThing.a << endl;
    }
```

However, again, there's a catch: now since `wholeThing` is of type `Foo`, the constructor will actually make a copy of that object during `wholeThing=f`. Just the same as it was when `b=f.a`, but now it remembers a copy of whole f.

Of course, it's only matter of type. You can store a reference instead of whole-Foo, but it needs a bit different initialization syntax:

```
class Bar
{
    ...
    Foo& wholeThing;

    Bar(Foo& f) :
        wholeThing(f)      // <=--- HERE
    {
                           // <=--- empty
    }

    void printvariable(void)
    {
        cout << "f.a is " << wholeThing.a << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. What are the best resources I can refer to find how this initializing works in the background ie memory use and cost of operations. I am a beginner in C++ and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2877289: I understand, but sorry, I can't help you with that much more that what I already wrote. There are tons of similar resources, even on the StackOverflow itself. Just search for these terms: `pass parameter by value`, `pass parameter by reference`, and optionally, `by pointer`. All in context of C++! be careful with that. You will find some texts dealing with Java and C#, since terms by-value and by-reference also is relevant to them, and different. Or grab any C++ tutorial or book. Pass-by-XXX distinction is so important that it is always explained near `methods` or `functions`